# Node.js and phantom issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, phantomjs

I'm playing around with Node.js and the node phantom module that is available. But I seem to be stuck at a basic level, and can't get this basic piece of code to work:

```
var phantom = require('phantom');
phantom.create(function(ph) {
  return ph.createPage(function(page) {
    return page.open("http://www.google.com", function(status) {
      console.log("opened google? ", status);
      return page.evaluate((function() {
        return document.title;
      }), function(result) {
        console.log('Page title is ' + result);
        return ph.exit();
      });
    });
  });
});
```

I can't really figure out why the console messages don't appear? This happen to be in some phantom scope, I guess, but would it be possible for me to have the messages be parsed on to node? Or is the problem something completely else?

Comment: Maybe phantom isn't loaded.. Did you try a console.log after 
phantom.create(function(ph) {, or ph.createPage(function(page) {

Comment: Also make sure that you don't have a x86_64 vs. i686 mismatch in the libraries that phantom needs.  See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17002351/node-phantom-createpage-never-calls-callback/17137960#17137960

Answer (score 0):

From the readme:

First, make sure PhantomJS is installed. This module expects the phantomjs binary to be in PATH somewhere. In other words, type this:

```
$ phantomjs
```

If that works, so will phantomjs-node. It's only been tested with PhantomJS 1.3, and almost certainly doesn't work with anything older.

if that doesnt work (what i expect) install phantomjs: http://phantomjs.org/download.html

Comment: PhantomJS is installed. I switched to the 'node-phantom' node-package and I did work without any problems.